# errors after building omnet++ project

Tags: c++, gcc, omnet++

I am trying to test a source code and a header file (for mac layer) that is already exists in mixim. I just copied the (.cc) and (.h) files from scr folder in mixim and I have paste it in my project folder. and I also referred to the class in the (.NED) file of the mac layer. Unfortunately, I keep getting the same errors every time I tried to build the project. The errors are as follows:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
make: *** [out/gcc-debug//WLAN_CSMA_test2.exe] Error 1  WLAN_CSMA_test2         C/C++ Problem
recipe for target 'out/gcc-debug//WLAN_CSMA_test2.exe' failed   Makefile    ‪/WLAN_CSMA_test2‬  line 107    C/C++ Problem
```

A shot from the makefile (line 107 is bold):

```
####(#Main target
all: $O/$(TARGET)
    $(Q)$(LN) $O/$(TARGET) .

$O/$(TARGET): $(OBJS)  $(wildcard $(EXTRA_OBJS)) Makefile
    **@$(MKPATH) $O**
    @echo Creating executable: $@
    $(Q)$(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $O/$(TARGET)  $(OBJS) $(EXTRA_OBJS) $(AS_NEEDED_OFF) $(WHOLE_ARCHIVE_ON) $(LIBS) $(WHOLE_ARCHIVE_OFF) $(OMNETPP_LIBS)

.PHONY: all clean cleanall depend msgheaders

.SUFFIXES: .cc
```

---

How can I fix this? Is there any other way that I can use to test the built-in source codes?

Thank you in advance.
Ohood.

Comment: The real error message is missing from this question. i.e. what appears before the final lines of the make's output.

Comment: Dear Rudi,
The complete error message is shown in the question. 
However, I solved this by modifying the module without changing its location (in the modules folder)

Best regards,,
Ohood

Comment: @OhoodAlkarney if you jhave managed to solve this issue, please make sure to append your solution as a sub-section to the end of your question, or use the **answer own question** option. So the solution remains here as future reference to the others